# Hello World in SOAP (java). How to fix it?

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to create a simple SOAP service and a SOAP client in order to run some performance tests.
I'm a newbie in the usage of SOAP and I'm simply trying to adapt some code that I've found on several forums.
Considering that this test will run on an embedded device I would prefer to avoid huge frameworks/libraries.
I would prefer to code in java without hacking with XML.

In the code below I'm trying to call the "sayHello" method and get the result. It's incomplete (argument is missing) but I would like to fix it in order to have a starting point for my tests.

Can you help me to fix this example code?

This is the code of the service class

```
@WebService(name = "Hello", targetNamespace = "http://localhost")
public class Hello
{
    private String message = new String("Hello, ");

    public void Hello()
    {
    }

    public String sayHello(String name)
    {
        return message + name + ".";
    }

}
```

This is the code of the server class:

```
public class Server
{
protected Server() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Starting Server");
    Object implementor = new Hello();
    String address = "http://localhost:9000/";
    Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    new Server();
    System.out.println("Server ready...");

    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
    System.out.println("Server exiting");
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

This is the code of a client class that is intended to send a request to the server calling the request() method:

```
public class Sender
{

.
.
.

    public void request() throws Exception
    {
        // Building the request document
        SOAPMessage reqMsg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = reqMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
        body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("Hello"));

        // Connecting and calling
        SOAPConnection con = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance()
                .createConnection();
        SOAPMessage resMsg = con.call(reqMsg, "http://localhost:9000/");
        con.close();

        // Showing output
        System.out.println("\n\nRequest:");
        reqMsg.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("\n\nResponse:");
        resMsg.writeTo(System.out);
    }

}
```

The output of the client looks like:

```
Request:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><Hello/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>S:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {}Hello</faultstring></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you call Hello, but you don't tell server which method to act on.

Comment: you could also do it less verbosely using example "Creating a Web Services Client in the NetBeans IDE 5.5" from [http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/)

Comment: use axis http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/

Comment: @Artem : event putting body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("sayHello")); the result is the same. What is the correct syntax ? "Hello/sayHello" ?

Comment: @Artem 2 : Intresting. I'm using Eclipse but probably that solution is portable from Netbeans.

Comment: What if you annotate your sayHello method with @WebMethod? And then generate a wsdl as it's shown in tutorial.

Comment: @aishwarya WS implementation choice was not among his questions.

Comment: look at this one for eclipse plugin [http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ws/](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ws/)

Comment: @ArtemOboturov no but if all he wants is a hello world to get started with soap, it would help him to pick the right and popular technologies.

Comment: @aishwarya it doesn't matter which implementation he will choose if don't know how to use standard interfaces and annotations. It's more a question of learning.

Comment: @aishwarya I need to run some test on embedded hardware so I cannot install a lot of libraries/frameworks like Axis/Maven ...because I have some constaints in terms of space and load. I've found a way to implement a simple SOAP service through standard Java environment and I would like to keep this way. Your solution is valid and intresting but it seems to be more feasible on a production server than on an embedded device.

Comment: @ALL : if you propose an answer I can vote :)